# CSS Esconder Elementos usando apenas css

Tags: html, css

Dado o seguinte trecho de código:

```
  <div class="ui stackable inverted blue container menu">
    <a class="item" href="/menu">
        logo
    </a>
    <a class="item" href="/menu">
        <i class="large settings  icon"></i>
        <span>Distribui&ccedil;&atilde;o Autom&aacute;tica</span>
    </a>

     <a class="item disabled" href="#" >
        <i class="large options icon "></i>
        <span>Distribui&ccedil;&atilde;o Manual</span>
    </a>

    <a class="item" href="/users">
        <i class="large users icon"></i>
        <span>Usu&aacute;rios</span>
    </a>

    <a class="item" href="/pesquisar_acoes">
        <i class="large search icon"></i>
        <span>Pesquisar</span>
    </a>


    <div class="ui pointing dropdown link item">
        <span class="text"><i class="large line chart icon"></i>Relatórios</span>
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="menu">
            {#<div class="header">Categories</div>#}

            <a class="item" href="/acoes_cadastradas">Ações Cadastradas</a>

            <div class="divider"></div>

            <a class="item" href="/relatorio_erros">Erros na Distribuição</a>
            <a class="item" href="/relatorio_distribuicao"> Processos Distribuídos</a>
        </div>
    </div>




    <a class="item" href="/desloga">
        <span class="ui teal button"><i class="sign out icon"></i> Sair</span></a>




</div>
```

Preciso que ao redimensionar a tela para um max-width = 792px, fique visível apenas a tag  que contém a palavra LOGO. As demais devem ser ocultadas.
Como fazer isso usando apenas css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das soluções seria a seguinte :

Utilizando `media queries` e `display:none` em conjunto `display:block`.

Há varios caminhos usando os seletores do css, ai vai da criatividade.

```html
<div class="ui stackable inverted blue container menu">
    <a class="item" href="/menu">
        logo
    </a>
    <a class="item" href="/menu">
        <i class="large settings  icon"></i>
        <span>Distribui&ccedil;&atilde;o Autom&aacute;tica</span>
    </a>

     <a class="item disabled" href="#" >
        <i class="large options icon "></i>
        <span>Distribui&ccedil;&atilde;o Manual</span>
    </a>

    <a class="item" href="/users">
        <i class="large users icon"></i>
        <span>Usu&aacute;rios</span>
    </a>

    <a class="item" href="/pesquisar_acoes">
        <i class="large search icon"></i>
        <span>Pesquisar</span>
    </a>


    <div class="ui pointing dropdown link item">
        <span class="text"><i class="large line chart icon"></i>Relatórios</span>
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="menu">
            {#<div class="header">Categories</div>#}

            <a class="item" href="/acoes_cadastradas">Ações Cadastradas</a>

            <div class="divider"></div>

            <a class="item" href="/relatorio_erros">Erros na Distribuição</a>
            <a class="item" href="/relatorio_distribuicao"> Processos Distribuídos</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="item" href="/desloga">
        <span class="ui teal button"><i class="sign out icon"></i> Sair</span></a>
</div>

<style>
@media(max-width:792px){
 a, .pointing{display:none;}
 a:first-child{display: block;}
 
}
</style>
```

- sobre seletores: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o @media do CSS3 (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)
para criar a regra de quando aplicar um certo estilo a determinado elemento, 
e aplicar

```
display: none;
```

para os elementos que devem ser escondidos caso a regra seja verdadeira.